# Would adding enums to my class make my code more compact or efficient?

Tags: c#, enum

I am working on a C# class library for my colleagues to use when programming industrial cameras.

I'm trying to determine both the most compact and elegant method to write the class. The commands are strings, of which much is duplicated, for example

```
1) cmdCamera ID:1 Pan:Right Speed:127
2) cmdCamera ID:1 Home
3) cmdCamera ID:1 Focus:Auto or cmdCamera ID:1 Focus:Manual
```

..... you get the idea....

My first iteration of the class is just a series of methods for the user to call

```
1) private void CameraMove (int CameraID, string Direction, int Speed)
 (then use StringBuilder to create string to send to camera)
2) private void CameraHome()
 (send string to camera)
3) private void AutoFocus (bool AF)
 (send string to camera)
```

While this works fine, it seems to me there should be more compact way to build the libary.

I thought I might be able to use an enumeration so the end user could insert something like:

```
 CameraMove.Pan = Right
 CameraMove.Speed = 127
```

In the class libary, I could use then Switch to parse the command and concatenate everything into the command string for the camera.

Thoughts on this strategy? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a way to make it more compact; you need all of the things that those functions do.  The enum sounds like a reasonable idea.

Comment: Enums never make code more compact or efficient vs. using integers.  (But they shouldn't make it *less* efficient either.)  What they do is make it more *readable*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will make things more *compact*, but it will make them more *clear*. You should really strive for that.

Instead of having a string for Pan-direction, using an enum is an excellent way to indicate that only a limited number of values can be passed. It also greatly reduces the amount of validation you need to do as the compiler does that for you. There is no way to pass "foo" as a pan-direction.

Speed seems like a good candidate for a small value object. You can have a PanSpeed-object that takes the speed as an integer and encapsulates the int value. This allows you to validate the speed-integer and limit it to a valid range (I'm assuming it to be some non-negative number that has an upper limit).

Comment: Your comment about encapsulating the int value for speed is a valuable one.

Answer (score 0):

@JDT - thanks for the idea.

```
private void CameraTilt(int speed, string direction)
      {
                if (speed > 20)
                {
                    speed = 20;
                }
                else if (speed < 0)
                {
                    speed = 0;
                }

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("camera tilt ");
                sb.Append(direction);
                sb.Append(" ");
                sb.Append(Convert.ToString(speed));
                string _tilt = sb.ToString();

                SendToCamera(_tilt);

            }
```